How do you know when a two-port subcircuit has no parameters of a given type?
In my class it was said that certain two-ports might not make sense with certain parameters when attempting to represent them, but we never looked into cases where it was just impossible to obtain the Y, Z, H or T parameters outright. I then looked at an example in a book that showcases one such case where the Z parameters just don't exist because the hypothesis under which those were defined was not met, although I think it tries to make it more obvious in that scenario. But I think I still can't tell immediately whether a given subcircuit will have a given representation or not, I don't think I could tell unless I try to obtain them in the first place and arrive at an incongruence. Is there a general way you'd be able to tell by just looking at it or does it come with practice?

Image from textbook, Linear Circuit Analysis by Artis Davis
